# Atualização dinâmica sem atualizar a página

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Opa pessoal, tudo certo?

Seguinte, eu estou fazendo uma área administrativa e gostaria que o conteúdo atualizasse dinamicamente sem a necessidade de atualizar a página para ver se tem algo novo. Por exemplo, se o administrador está na página de pedidos e entra um novo pedido, gostaria que a tabela já atualizasse e exibisse esse novo pedido, sem precisar carregar a página para ver se tem algo novo.

Ou caso não esteja na página de pedidos, seria exibido uma notificação, como tem aqui no stackoverflow ou no facebook, etc..

Tentei procurar algo assim, mas por enquanto não encontrei nada. As linguagens que estou utilizando são: PHP (banco de dados), JSON (passar as infos do banco para o site), Jquery/AJAX para deixar as coisas dinâmicas e HTML/CSS.

Eu tenho os códigos funcionais para ler o DB, criar o JSON, escrever as tabelas no site etc.. Apenas não consegui fazer essas atualizações dinâmicas e sistema de notificação, sem necessidade do refresh.

Alguém consegue me ajudar com isso? Como começar? Algum link de referência para eu aprender isso? Conheço um pouco de Jquery/Ajax, mas nada avançado.

Obrigado.

Edit: Andei pesquisando e encontrei esse código em Jquery:

```
var $container = $("#mytable");
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $container;
    console.log("loaded");
}, 10000);
```

Porém ele não está funcionando. Ele faz o load da div, o console mostra que foi carregado, mas a tabela não atualiza com os novos valores.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Olá. Você está no caminho certo por isso irei ser objetivo. Existem diversas maneiras de se chegar a este resultado. O código que você está usando está incompleto, por isso não funciona, você tem que trazer o novo resultado e adiciona-lo a tabela. Segue um exemplo:

```
            var container = $("#mytable");
            var refreshId = setInterval(function(){ check(); }, 10000);

            function check() {

                $.getJSON("result.json", function(data){

                    console.log(data);

                    /*
                     1 - Se existir adiciona na tabela e exibe o alert
                     container.append('<tr><td>#001</td><td>exemplo</td></tr>');


                     2 - Se não existir apenas retorna falso;
                     return false; 
                     */

                });

            }
```

Ok. Agora temos um verificador de registro com time loop que irá adicionar o novo registro a tabela. Você poderá complementar a função adicionando o recurso de aviso/notificação. Existem vários Plugins em jQuery. Neste link, você irá encontrar mais de 35 opções para adequar ao seu projeto: http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-notification-plugin/

Bem, agora temos a questão de checagem dos novos registros, uma solução simples é passar uma $_SESSION no PHP para quando realizar a consulta de checagem (setTimeinterval) que irá executar o getJSON no PHP saber se o resultado encontrado realmente é ou não novo.

Tudo irá depender da forma como o seu projeto está sendo desenvolvido. Não sei, se você possui uma tabela de atividade dos usuários para saber se já foi visto o pedido ou não em fim. Você precisa elaborar uma forma de comparar e detectar esse novo registro.

Boa sorte!