# Atualizar Div HTML PHP Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, div

Estou com alguns problemas ao atualizar uma div sem atualizar a página inteira.
Segue o código:

```
<div class="main" align="justify">
     <div id="mensagens">
          <?php echo file_get_contents('arquivo.txt'); ?>
     </div>
...
```

Já pensei em criar um "frame" - não sei bem se esse seria o nome - e usar "meta refresh" para atualizar dentro dele.

Minha duvida é: Como atualizar esse Div usando o PHP ou Javascript? E, se possível, teria como atualizar esse Div sempre que houver uma mudança no "arquivo.txt"?

*Atualização*

O "arquivo.txt" é atualizado normalmente:

```
$texto = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
$string = $texto . "\n";
$fp = fopen('arquivo.txt', 'a');
$fw = fwrite($fp, $string);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Você pode usar `.ajax` ou `.get` do jQuery. Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54525/atualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-din%C3%A2mica-sem-atualizar-a-p%C3%A1gina) uma pergunta relacionada com `getJSON`.

Comment: Como/porque é que esse "arquivo.txt" é alterado?

Comment: O arquivo.txt seria como um "banco de dados". Os usuários enviam o conteúdo para lá, em vez de usar um banco de dados normal. Lá esta tudo configurado e organizado de acordo com a saída que eu quero.

Comment: Isto é algum sistema para teste ?

Comment: Sim, seria só uma "experimento".

Comment: Também recomendo o uso do Ajax

Answer (score 2):

Tente isso:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Dados:</label>
    <input name="text" id="text" value="#Teste"><br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" id="btn_submit">Confirma</button>
    <div id="resultado"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn_submit').click(function () {
        grava();
    });
    $.post("grava.php", {},
    function (resp) {
        $('#resultado').html(resp);
    });    
});

function grava() {
    $.post("grava.php", {
        text: $("#text").val()
    },
    function (resp) {
        $('#resultado').html(resp);
    });
}
```

**grava.php**

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['text'])) {
    $texto = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
    $string = $texto . ";\n";
    $fp = fopen('arquivo.txt', 'a');
    $fw = fwrite($fp, $string);
    fclose($fp);
}
echo file_get_contents('arquivo.txt');
```

**OBS:** dê permissão de gravação no diretório.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza o `setInterval()` para carregar o arquivo com intervalo de tempo.

Html:

```
<div id="rg">
    Texto desatualizado!
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
    <script>
        setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET", //GET OU POST
                url: "/text.txt" //LOCAL DO ARQUIVO

            }).done(function (answer) {
                $('#rg').html(answer);//Executa se tiver sucesso

            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log("Request search failed: " + textStatus); //executa se falhar 
            });
        }, 2000); // Tempo para cada execução
    </script>
```

O `.html(answer);` vai colocar a informação recebida entre as tags de abertura e fechamento respectivas  e